# User defined table type with a check constraint

Tags: sql-server-2012, constraint, user-defined-type

I have a user defined table type where I want to make sure that a certain column is within a given range. This range however is defined in another table. So I thought I can use a check constraint on this column with a scalar valued function.

```
    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Accounts] AS TABLE(
    [AccountName] [varchar](25) NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT CHK_AccountName CHECK (dbo.validateAccountName(AccountName) = 1),
    [Sales] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Returns] [int] NOT NULL
);
```

However I get a syntax error, when I do the same on a regular table it works. Based on MSFT documentation check constraints should be ok on table types. What am I missing here ? Any better approach to validate input on a table type ?

Answer (score 1):

Although table types do allow unnamed `CHECK` constraints, it is not possible to use a user-defined function inside one.

The error message is:

> Msg 2785 Level 16 State 1 Line 3
>   User-defined functions, user-defined aggregates, CLR types, and methods on CLR types are not allowed in expressions in this context.
>   Msg 1750 Level 16 State 0 Line 1
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

See the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=169c327a96d4f6abd4cff3c4fddb06fe) demo

Answer (score -2):

Try this solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330114/user-defined-table-type-with-check-constraint

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Accounts] AS TABLE(
    [AccountName] [varchar](25) NOT NULL 
         CHECK (dbo.validateAccountName(AccountName) = 1),
    [Sales] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Returns] [int] NOT NULL
);
```